# About the paper "Deep Unsupervised Learning using Nonequilibrium Thermodynamics"

Tags: machine-learning, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process

I have spent some time studying the paper [Deep Unsupervised Learning using
Nonequilibrium Thermodynamics](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.03585.pdf). At page 5, the authors discuss the following integral:

$$\int d\mathbf{x}^{(1\cdots T)}q(\mathbf{x}^{(1\cdots T)}|\mathbf{x}^{(0)})\cdot p(\mathbf{x}^{(T)})
\prod_{t=1}^T \dfrac{p(\mathbf{x}^{(t-1)}|\mathbf{x}^{(t)})}{q(\mathbf{x}^{(t)}|\mathbf{x}^{(t-1)})}$$
commenting that (if I understand correctly) if [image: quasi-static] (quasi-static limit) then "only a single sample from [image: q (x(1···T )|x(0))] is required to exactly evaluate the above integral, as can be seen by substitution". Now I'm *guessing* this means that
$$ p(\mathbf{x}^{(T)})
\prod_{t=1}^T \dfrac{p(\mathbf{x}^{(t-1)}|\mathbf{x}^{(t)})}{q(\mathbf{x}^{(t)}|\mathbf{x}^{(t-1)})}$$
becomes a constant in the quasi-static limit but would appreciate any comment as I am very dubious about my understanding.

Comment: Without looking at the paper, I suspect both $p$ and $q$ are joint densities for Markov chains.

Comment: Hi thank you for your comment; p and q indicate both conditional and joint densities in a Markov Chain, depending by the usual notation.

Answer (score 1):

I just started reading the paper. Somehow I agree with your understanding, although I'm not sure I completely get the math of it. One clue is that in Section 2.4, under Equation (14), they mention that the Jensen inequality in Equation (13) becomes equality (E(f(x)) <= f(E(x)) for concave functions) with the quasi-static process. We know this only happens when x = E(x), ie. x is constant (check out Andrew Ng's CS229 note 8 on expectation maximization).

Comment: Hi RachelD,
thank you for your contribution. I did go through the same path of mind reading that part; apparently the Jansen inequality becomes an equality if 'f' is an affine transform (obviously 'log' is not) or, as you say, if x is constant, which corresponds to the term was pointing in my question.

Comment: I add here two further thoughts:
1) AFAIU, the Jansen inequality becoming an equality could be not essential for the optimization procedure. In fact, finding the max of the lower bound by training an ANN would indirectly push up the likelihood  (i.e. the quantity the lower bound is less or equal to)
2) the Jarzynski equality, mentioned in the paper, is also an equality that somehow, on average, replaces an inequality (the second law of thermodynamics). I'm wondering if the reasoning used there could be of any help for my doubt.
I'd very much like to read your views on these thoughts. thanks